# Access companion object from base trait

Tags: scala

If I define a trait, I can access successor's fields. But what if one of those fields is in companion object (e.g. for speed, as static member), can I access it too?

Is there a relationship between TheTrait object and TheSuccessor object, as with TheTrait trait and TheSuccessor class?

Comment: if it's public, you can use fields of companion object anywhere. If they are private, it seems you cannot.

Comment: Any of implementations may have own companion. I want to be able to access it without massive code duplication (manually create extra trait for companions and extend it everywhere).

Comment: can you give a small example?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell you cant. You could either let the companion object implement the trait, or maybe define an abstract method in the trait. Implementing classes could then provide access to the companion object by implementing the method.